# Properties Lebesgue measure. open set, closed set, compact set.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, supremum-and-infimum

I'm trying to solve this following problem:

1) M $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Lebesgue mesurable set.
Show that for every $\varepsilon$ > 0 there is a open set U $\supset$ M such that $\lambda$(U\M) < $\varepsilon$. 
Remark: [ U := $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty$ $U_i$ , $U_i$ open ] 
I was able to prove this.

2) Now show that:
$\lambda$(M) = inf{ $\lambda$(U) : U open , U $\supset$ M } = sup { $\lambda$(A) : A closed,  A $\subset$ M } = sup {$\lambda$(K) : K compact, K $\subset$ M }

I've already proved the first equality.  But I don't have any idea how to prove the other equalities. 
for inf{ $\lambda$(U) : U open , U $\supset$ M } = sup { $\lambda$(A) : A closed,  A $\subset$ M } we could take a open set O and consider the complement of O ?

for sup { $\lambda$(A) : A closed,  A $\subset$ M } = sup {$\lambda$(K) : K compact, K $\subset$ M } we could take A closed set and consider $A_k$ = A$\cap$ [-k,k] , k $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ ?

Please help me guys.
Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: did it by my own. Thank you anyways.